# How do I find, download and install a trained PaddleOCR model?

Tags: python, ocr, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

Tell me how to find and install a trained OCR model for [PaddleOCR](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR)? Because I got confused in the official documentation on the GitHub. Looking for a "smart and complete" OCR model for PaddleOCR for Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the trained model in [model_list](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.5/doc/doc_en/models_list_en.md) for PaddleOCR.

If you need an English model, it is recommended **ch_PP-OCRv3_det** + **en_PP-OCRv3_rec**